# Allow multiple people to submit iOS/Mac App Store apps, without changing profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

We have a team of developers working on an iOS app, and any one of them should be able to submit the app to the App Store.

Is it possible to achieve this without having to change the provisioning profile each time before submission? The problem is that developers are constantly overwriting each other's provision profile project setting in source control.

I know it's possible for development builds as multiple certificates can be part of the same profile, but it seems this isn't possible for distribution profiles.

Short of copying and distributing private keys amongst developers, is there a way to achieve this?